# Quizzes from Cognito forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Cognito forms is awesome. Well done.  I have made a few forms, and it's very easy.  However I am wondering if you have done or are doing an extension that would allow us to make quizzes out of forms?  ..like the quiz add-on the GravityForms has?

I'd like to see graded scoring ... scores given according to answers and a grade given or emailed to the responded at the end of the quiz.

Comment: I think this is best directed to their customer support or feedback.  This site is for end-user questions on a multitude of web applications, but I don't think this is something we can really answer for you here.

Comment: Well, it looks like the support found him ☺

Answer (score 2):

I work with support for [Cognito Forms](http://www.cognitoforms.com).  We actually have a template in the works to provide this functionality.

In the meantime, you can use the instructions in this blog post to create your own quizzes:
http://blog.cognitoforms.com/using-ifthen-statements-on-your-cognito-forms-1

Hope that helps!
Best,
Nick